# Comparing contents of a div to string in JS

Tags: javascript, html

My if statement is not returning the correct response in the following code. I'm trying to take the contents of my message div with document.querySelector, store it in the secret_saying variable, and compare it to a string. However, even though the contents of my message div match the string, the response and image path that show up are incorrect. Any thoughts?

```
<div id="message">
An Eagle Flies at Midnight
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>

<img src="">

<script>

var secret_saying = document.querySelector('#message').textContent;
var response = "";
var image_path = "";

if (secret_saying === "An Eagle Flies at Midnight") {
  response = "You may pass";
  image_path = "https://www.craftsmanfounder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/open-door-with-awesome-ideas-and-open-door.jpg.png";
} else {
  response = "Release the hounds!";
  image_path = "http://www.dogbreedplus.com/images/puredogss.png";
}

document.querySelector('#result').textContent = response
document.querySelector('img').src = image_path

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra whitespace in `#message` div. You should either have it trimmed yourself:

```
<div id="message">An Eagle Flies at Midnight</div>
```

or trim it in your JS code:

```
var secret_saying = document.querySelector('#message').textContent.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to [`.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the `textContent` as it contents whitespaces

```js
var secret_saying = document.querySelector('#message').textContent.trim();
var response = "";
var image_path = "";
if (secret_saying === "An Eagle Flies at Midnight") {
  response = "You may pass";
  image_path = "https://www.craftsmanfounder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/open-door-with-awesome-ideas-and-open-door.jpg.png";
} else {
  response = "Release the hounds!";
  image_path = "http://www.dogbreedplus.com/images/puredogss.png";
}

document.querySelector('#result').textContent = response
document.querySelector('img').src = image_path
```

```html
<div id="message">
An Eagle Flies at Midnight
</div>

<div id="result">
</div>

<img src="">
```

Comment: Or use a regular expression: `/\s*An Eagle Flies at Midnight\s*/.test(secret_saying)`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex expressions to validate input as well. Here are some references to help with regex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

```
var secret_saying = "An Eagle Flies at Midnight";
console.log(/^An Eagle Flies at Midnight$/.test(secret_saying)); //true
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79yxz55k/2/